# Different offsetLeft if TABLE element has border (IE vs Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

`offsetLeft` behaves different in IE and Chrome if the `offsetParent` is a TABLE element has set a border left:

IE does include the border
Chrome does NOT include the border

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/o4qcvqp6/1/

Result for IE:     td 3: **210**, span 3: 210

Result for Chrome: td 3: **200**, span 3: 210

Why do they behave different and is there any way to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different since there is no set standard, and each browser treats offsets and their parents differently, with different results. Checkout [this bug report on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=481076) for a good discussion.

You can check which browser is being used and display accordingly, although I would not recommend this

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;
var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;

if(isChrome){
  //format for Chrome
}
else if(isIE){
  //format for IE
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but only if the element is a TABLE or could there be other elements?

Comment: There are other elements which suffer from cross-browser UI issues. I'd recommend looking into using a UI framework, like Bootstrap or JQueryUI.